# Make a button in VB.net which will create 5 text boxes (next to each other) below the button

Tags: vb.net, button, gridview

I tried the code pasted below but it does not seem to work in vb.net. However, this creates only one text box and not where I exactly want it to be. My objective here is to create 5 text boxes under the respective labels. There will then be a button which will take in all the text inputs from the text boxes and show it in a grid view.

```
   Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Dim num As Integer
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim intcount As Integer



    For intcount = 0 To num() - 1

    Next
    Txtdynamic = New TextBox
    Txtdynamic.Width = 20
    Txtdynamic.Visible = True
    Txtdynamic.MaxLength = 1
    Txtdynamic.Location = New Point(pos() + 5, 0)
    pos = pos() + 30

End Sub

This is how my buttons with the labels look like:

<p>
            <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Add Member" />
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Add Joint" />
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Edit Member" />
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Edit Joint" />
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="See Joint Coordinate" />
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="See Member Coordinate" />
        </p>
        Joint #&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Coordinates&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; B.C&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Joint Loads&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; Settlements&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Joint Rotation<p>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: Your not using a loop. Yes that is not VB.Net so it won't work.

Comment: I need to create the text boxes next to each other, under the labels. I am not too sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: I just edited my question, this is what I have tried now to create the text box. Unfortunately, it is still not working. @DonA

Answer (score 0):

How are you supposed to make a loop if you put all the instructions outside the loop block?.

Try this way:

```
For i as short = 0 To 4 ' 0 1 2 3 4 = 5

    Txtdynamic = New TextBox
    Txtdynamic.Width = 20
    Txtdynamic.Visible = True
    Txtdynamic.MaxLength = 1
    Txtdynamic.Location = New Point(pos + 5, 0)
    pos += 30

Next
```

Anyways here you can see a random example of me to add controls in execution time:

```
Dim ControlArray(5) As CheckBox ' (5): The number of controls to create.

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For num As Int64 = 0 To ControlArray.LongLength - 1

        ControlArray(num) = New CheckBox ' Create the control instance
        ControlArray(num).Name = "CheckBox " & num      ' Name example  : CheckBox 0
        ControlArray(num).Text = ControlArray(num).Name ' String example: CheckBox 0
        ControlArray(num).Top = num * 20 ' Adjust the location of each control.
        Me.Controls.Add(ControlArray(num)) ' Add the control to a control collection.
        AddHandler ControlArray(num).CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBoxSub ' Add a event handler to a procedure.

    Next

End Sub

Public Sub CheckBoxSub(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) ' Procedure which is handling the controls.

    If sender.Checked = True Then MsgBox(sender.name & " is checked") Else MsgBox(sender.name & " is unchecked")

    ControlArray(2).Text = "Check Me!" ' CheckBox 2.Text = "Check Me!"

End Sub
```

Comment: This keeps giving me this error: "error BC30456: 'location' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'."

Comment: My answer is related to `Winforms`, I don't know how to do it in `ASP.NET`, sorry. Check here and goodluck: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx

Comment: I am not being able to figure it out. Can anyone please help me out? I have tried multiple times and it does not seem to work